# How to calculate the cost or number of operations in a matrix multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

Suppose there are three matrixes named A(with dimension 10 X 30), B(with dimension 30 X 5), and C(with dimension 5 X 60).

```
(AB)C = (10×30×5) + (10×5×60) = 1500 + 3000 = 4500 operations
A(BC) = (30×5×60) + (10×30×60) = 9000 + 18000 = 27000 operations
```

.

How are they{(AB)C  and A(BC)} calculated?
Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you want to know how (AB) is calculated? Or do you only want to know how (AB)C is calculated, given (AB)?

Comment: I want to know how (AB)C    or A(BC) is calculated...

Answer (score 0):

`(AB)C` represents two matrix multiplications:

```
X = AB
Y = XC
```

To calculate the number of operations for `(AB)C`, first calculate the number of operations for each of the two individual matrix multiplications:

```
X = AB = (10×30×5)
Y = XC = (10×5×60)
```

Then add them:

```
Y = (AB)C = (10×30×5) + (10×5×60)
```

This notation abuses the `=` sign to mean sometimes "matrix equals matrix" and sometimes "matrix requires that number of operations to calculate". I hope you are not getting confused by that.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you calculate `Y=XC=(10x5x60)`.
i mean how did you write so